# How to connect Apollo client with Apollo server

Tags: typescript, apollo-client, apollo-server

I'm following the Apollo tutorial at https://www.apollographql.com/docs/tutorial/client/.  My server is running successfully on `localhost:4000`, and my client is running on `localhost:3000`.  Client compiled successfully, yet I'm getting a 400 error in the browser, and it's pointing to an Apollo error:

`Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network error: Response not successful: Received status code 400 at new ApolloError (bundle.esm.js:76)`.

The tutorial uses TypeScript for the client, which I didn't have installed, so I installed that globally, but I have not made any other changes to the client beyond what the tutorial has mentioned.  Not sure if that's the issue.

For reference, the tutorial's repo is at https://github.com/apollographql/fullstack-tutorial.

Comment: A 400 error means your query itself is invalid or malformed. Inspect the `error` object returned by the `useQuery` hook to determine the cause. You can also look at the raw response from the server in your browser's dev tools. The `errors` array will include details about what was wrong with your query.

Answer (score 1):

Solved: turns out I accidentally deleted a schema type's field, which was causing the 400. There was also a compilation error from following this tutorial (a named import in another file was throwing an error), but I resolved that by making it a default import.